# Introduction to ASP.NET MVC 5 tutorial and LocalDB

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, localdb

I am going through [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started) and I'm stuck on step 5 - Creating a Connection String and Working with SQL Server LocalDB. The error I get is:

```
There was an error running the selected code generator:

'Unable to retrieve metadata for 'MvcMovie.Models.Movie'. Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.'
```

I have searched the internet for an answer **for days**. I have tried many solutions, but none have worked. I have checked and re-checked the code, I have Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web with update 1 on a Windows 7 64-bit PC. Can anyone help me figure this out using LocalDB and not another DB product?

Here is the web.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcMovie-20140207025827.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcMovie-20140207025827;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="MovieDBContext"
      connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movie.mdf;Initial Catalog=Movies;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    />

  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

I have already answered some questions on the ASP.NET forum and posted screenshots so please read this over - [Here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1966867/5627281.aspx?Re%20Introduction%20to%20ASP%20NET%20MVC%205%20tutorial%20and%20LocalDB)

Comment: I'm going to take a stab in the dark...have you tried to include 'Integrated security in your second connection string?

Comment: It seems your website is looking for the localDb file in app_data. Is it present there?

Comment: The MovieDBContext connection string does include Integrated Security = true. No the localDb is not showing up in app_data. According to the tutorial the step I get the error on is supposed to add it.

Comment: Can you post the code for your db context? Or for that matter can you push your codebase up to github and make it public so others can repo the problem?

Comment: I had no issues with going through the same tutorial step on my personal Windows 8.1 PC. So I guess it is specific to my work computer.

Comment: Would you please show the code of Model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it was an issue with one computer. I was able to do the same thing on another computer.

Answer (score 1):

Please modify the Connection String as shown below:

```
<add name="MovieDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

You can check the following article for further reference:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/working-with-model-class-and-connection-string-in-mvc-5/

Please check the Event Viewer details for your application. If the LocalDb is corrupted then run the following commands:

```
SqlLocalDB Create C
```